# Answering a flawed Mathletes question (finding $x^2 + y^2 = p$ given $p$ for large $p$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

There was a mathletes meet today (high school) and this was one of the questions:

"-Some background on Fermat's 4k+1 sum of square theorem- One such prime is $367369$. What integers $x, y$ satisfy $x^2 + y^2 = 367369$?"

Is there any way to have done this problem otherwise without just massive guess and check (and luck)? (Note that the time constraint is $10$ minutes for $2$ problems). If you're wondering, the correct answer was $\{420, 437\}$.

So, any ideas? Personally I think the guy just forgot to give us some information..

Comment: Oh that's funny, I put "<backstory of fermat's 4k+1 sum of square theorem>" but the <'s made it so it didn't appear.

Comment: Right away you should see by putting $367,369$ approx $400,000$, dividing by $2$ and taking a square root, you only need to check $x$ from $1$ to $<500$.

Comment: @nayrb: by hand, in $5$ minutes?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Check, as in find some clever way to rule out a bunch of cases, then check the remaining few.

Comment: This is equivalent to factoring $367369$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the contest rules -- but is it permitted to use (standard, not necessarily programmable) calculators or do you have to do computations with pen and paper?

Comment: @Peter: most competitions don't allow calculators.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan My question stems from [this page](http://mathleteschallenge.com/rules/) mention of calculators; which could make quite a bit of difference.

Comment: @Peter: "mathletes" is a generic term; it doesn't refer to a specific competition. If you look at that page you'll see that the problem / time ratio doesn't match.

Comment: Rules:

No calculator. Pen and paper. Ten minutes for two problems (three rounds) -- the other problem was easy, so say ten minutes for this one.

Comment: Personally I thought it would be $600$ and some other number, which gave an almost-answer of $600^2 + 87^2 = 367569$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of casework by working modulo small powers of primes and seeing what constraints that puts on $x, y$ (then combining them using the chinese remainder theorem). For example,

- $367369 \equiv 1 \bmod 8$, and using the fact that $x^2 \equiv 0, 1, 4 \bmod 8$ it follows that exactly one of $x$ or $y$ must be divisible by $4$ and the other one must be odd.
- $367369 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, and using the fact that $x^2 \equiv 0, 1 \bmod 3$ it follows that exactly one of $x$ or $y$ must be divisible by $3$.
- $367369 \equiv 4 \bmod 5$, and using the fact that $x^2 \equiv 0, 1, 4 \bmod 5$ it follows that exactly one of $x$ or $y$ must be divisible by $5$ and the other one must be congruent to $2, 3 \bmod 5$.

This gets you some information $\bmod 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 60$, although unfortunately you don't know which of $x$ or $y$ satisfy the conditions above so you do still need to break into several cases. The easiest case to handle is the case where, say, $x$ satisfies all of the divisibility constraints, so if you assume $x$ is divisible by $60$ then you would only need to check the cases $x = 0, 60, 120, ..., 480$ as nayrb explained in the comments. Moreover, since $367369$ is fairly large it's a good idea to check the largest possibilities first, so checking $x = 480$ and then $x = 420$ would've finished the problem.

Comment: nayrb's comment only applies if $x$ and $y$ are interchangeable; once you require $x$ to be divisible by $60$, you'd have to go all the way up to $600$ to cover all possibilities.